# Can I instantiate/inflate a View from XML?

Tags: android

I have a Button View. Would I have to wrap it in a Layout in order to be able to inflate instances of it in an Activity? Is there a similar pattern for View's, so that I can set it up once, declaratively, and create multiple instances of it?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I think I'm missing something about layouts. Are they meant to be declared as templates that can be instantiated *anywhere*? Or can they only be used within another specific layout?

Example:

I have a ScrollView Layout defined in contents.xml. It is totally on its own, not included by any other layouts. In my activity, setContentView is called on my main layout. Is it possible for me to instantiate a copy of contents.xml? Do I need to change the "contentView" somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap it. The following XML can be inflated directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Button ... />
```

Comment: What API do I use to inflate it? There are hints of a seemingly deprecated getViewInflate() method, but I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it, but the documentation for LayoutInflater says it can inflate: "an XML layout resource." I suppose a View could be considered a layout "resource" even though it's not a layout, but I was under the impression that you could only use a LayoutInflater for layouts. I'll give it a try tonight and post back with results.

Comment: But a View is not a Layout (necessarily). Which is why I'm not sure a LayoutInflater would work for all views.

Comment: I meant to test this but I think I'm running into more fundamental issues (see edit in OP).

Comment: LayoutInflater works with all views. A "layout" is a generic term for an XML file that describes a UI or a piece of UI. A layout can be made of a single View, or of a ViewGroup that contains other Views/ViewGroups. And if you look at the LayoutInflater API you will see that it returns a View.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate that view in an `LinearLayout` and then you are good to inflate that layout throughout your application.

Comment: That's what I figured... but is that a good practice? Seems kind of like a work-around because it doesn't get you the same structure as you could get programmatically since you have extra wrapper Layouts. I'm guessing it wouldn't really impact performance though.

Comment: You don't need the extra LinearLayout.